# Integration of $\int_1^2 x(2x-3)^4 \, dx$ by substitution

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

An exam question: $$\int_1^2 x(2x-3)^4 \, dx\\
U = 2x - 3$$

I have rearranged to get $dx = dU/2$. So I am now at
$\int xU^4 \, dU$

I am not quite sure what to do with the $x$ as it is not cancelled out as I thought it would. Thanks for any help.

Comment: You could not let that integral on this form. You have to substitute every variable x by u

Comment: Ok, mookid is faster than me

Comment: Why do a substitution at all? This can be multiplied out quite easily to a polynomium.

Comment: @SBareS this looks simpler not to expand the 4th power. Imagine with $n$ instead of 4.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to substitute every instance of $x$.

You are then at
$$
\int \frac{U+3}2 U^4 \frac{dU}2$$
and then use the formula

$$
\int t^m dt = \frac {t^{m+1}}{m+1}
$$
Can you take it from here?

Comment: I get,
1/4∫U^5 + 3u^4 du = 1/4[1/6 u^6 + 1/15 u^5]

Which doesn't give the correct answer, so I've gone wrong somewhere

Comment: why 1/15?${{{{}}}}$

Comment: ahh yes, There's the error, it should be 3/5 shouldn't it ?

Comment: @gweno10 i think so :)

Answer (score 3):

Using capital $U$ and lower-case $u$ interchangeably gets perceived by mathematicians the way others perceive a spelling error, and moreover in many contexts the corresponding capital and lower-case letters refer to two different things in the same problem.  You've probably seen this in trigonometry where $a$ is the length of the side of a triangle and $A$ is the measure of the angle that is opposite that side.  In this sort of problem lower case is somewhat customary and I use it below:

\begin{align}
u & = 2x-3 \\[6pt]
du & = 2\,dx \\[6pt]
x & = \frac{u-3} 2 \\[6pt]
\int x(2x-3)^4\,dx & = \int\frac{u-3} 2 u^4 \left(\frac{du} 2\right) = \frac 1 4\int(u^5 - 3u^4)\,du = \cdots\cdots
\end{align}

Answer (score 3):

In the same spirit as Mookid's answer, consider a more general case $$I=\int (A+Bx)(C+Dx)^n\,dx$$ Change variable $C+Dx=u$, $x=\frac{u-C}{D}$, $dx=\frac{du}{D}$ $$I=\int\big(A+\frac{B (u-C)}{D}\big)u^n \,du=\int\big(A-\frac{B C}{D}+\frac{B u}{D})u^n\,du$$ $$I=\big(A-\frac{B C}{D}\big)\int u^n \, du+\frac{B }{D}\int u^{n+1} \, du$$ $$I=\big(A-\frac{B C}{D}\big)\frac{u^{n+1}}{n+1}+\frac{B }{D}\frac{u^{n+2}}{n+2}$$ Now, as jnh commented, $n$ can be as large as you want, rational, irrational, it does not make any difference.

Answer (score 0):

HINT:$$x(2x-3)^4=16\,{x}^{5}-96\,{x}^{4}+216\,{x}^{3}-216\,{x}^{2}+81\,x$$

Comment: I don't think this is the most clever move here...

Comment: but is is an move here

Comment: While this may work for small exponents, what about a more general solution to this problem? Given $x(2x-3)^n$ where $n$ is large, say $n>100$, this solution is completely inefficient (even for $n=4$ yours is not an ideal solution).  So in conclusion I have to agree with @mookid here. I regret to inform you that I have downvoted your answer.